# Running a simulation without using looping in R

Tags: r, simulation, montecarlo

I have the following code for a Monte Carlo simulation:

```
function (muC1,sigmaC1,muC2,sigmaC2,Msim=10000) { 
# a grand loop simulation program for the lifetime of 
# a simple system of components. This system has 
# two branches. The first branch fails when C1 fails.   
# The second branch fails as soon as either of C2 or C3 fails.
#
# get alpha's and lambda's for Gamma lifetime RVs from the 
# mu's and sigma's.
# Note C2 has the same distribution as C3, i.e. 
# alpha3=alpha2, lambda3=lambda2
lambda1 = muC1/sigmaC1^2
alpha1 = muC1*lambda1
lambda2 = muC2/sigmaC2^2
alpha2 = muC2*lambda2
#  
# initialize simulation summary holders
count.C1fail = 0   # number of times C1 fails before branch2
system.lifetime = rep(NA,Msim)
#
# begin grand loop
for (i in 1:Msim) {
C1 = rgamma(1,alpha1,lambda1)
C2 = rgamma(1,alpha2,lambda2)
C3 = rgamma(1,alpha2,lambda2)
branch2 = min(C2,C3)
system.lifetime[i] = max(C1,branch2)
if (C1 < branch2) count.C1fail = count.C1fail+1
} # end grand loop
#
# final summary calculations and wrapup
PC1fail = count.C1fail/Msim
hist(system.lifetime,main="Simulated System Lifetimes")
meanL = mean(system.lifetime)
stddevL = sd(system.lifetime)
MOEL95pct = 1.96*stddevL/sqrt(Msim)
out = list(muC1,sigmaC1,muC2,sigmaC2,Msim,PC1fail,meanL,MOEL95pct)
names(out) = c("muC1","sigmaC1","muC2","sigmaC2","Msim","PC1fail","meanL","MOEL95pct")
out 
}
```

This simulation works perfectly for what I need, but for an assignment I need to run the same simulation (muC1 = 100, sigmaC1 = 20, muC2 = 80, sigmaC2 = 40, Msim = 10000) WITHOUT a grand loop. Any tips?

Comment: Do you want to use recursion instead of a loop? Or use built-in vectorized functions?  It's not clear what you're having trouble with.

Comment: I believe vectorized functions. I'm new to learning R and I was given the code above and tasked with modifying the function to run the same simulation but without using a grand loop.

Comment: rgamma returns a vector of results. You want something like: `C1 = rgamma(Msim, alpha1, lambda1)` and similarly for C2 and C3. Then perform vectorized operations for the remaining operations in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eliminate the loop by just drawing all your random values at once.

```
C1 <- rgamma(Msim, alpha1, lambda1)
C2 <- rgamma(Msim, alpha2, lambda2)
C3 <- rgamma(Msim, alpha2, lambda2)
branch2 <- pmin(C2, C3)
system.lifetime <- pmax(C1, branch2)
count.C1fail <- sum(C1 < branch2)
```

Then since we want to operate on vectors rather that just two values, we switch from `min` and `max` to `pmin` and `pmax` (the vectorized versions of the function). Finally, to count events in vectors we often just `sum()` over TRUE/FALSE values because TRUE is converted to 1 and FALSE 0 so we just get the count of TRUE events.

Doing it this way also means that it's not necessary to initialize `count.C1fail` or `system.lifetime` ahead of time.